# Can I do transition in CollectionCell Class?

Tags: swift

I want to transition another ViewController Class when tablViewCell tapped. (TableView in CollectionView Cell)
so,I want to write to transition Code in tableViewCell Class.
How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign collectionview delegate to the view controller class inside the tableview cellforrow method. And assign tableview cell indexpath.row to its collectionview tag.

In collectionview didselect method write the transition Code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ...
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.collectionView.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected collectionview cell indexpath \(indexPath) in table view cell row \(collectionView.tag)")
        //push to next view controller from here
    }

}
```